# How to find out what introduces AVX flag

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++, makefile

I have a quite large x64 c++ program that is compiled with Visual Studio. There are two ways how do we compile it - one is with sln solution file (from IDE or through msbuild), another is through Makefile in VS command prompt (which then internally uses Visual Studio's cl.exe and link.exe).

Somehow I got into situation that binary build through **Makefile produces executable with /AVX instructions enabled, and I don't want that**, so I want to find out how to get rid of it.

I try to compile and link it without any parameters (especially without /arch:AVX). I hope that I compile and link the same sources and libs in both sln and Makefile.

What is the easy way how to find out where the AVX comes from? Project includes dozens of h/cpp files, around 40 own libs, 10 windows libs. How would you proceed?

Comment: Looking in the .cpp files won't give you a difference, since any `#pragma` there would affect the .sln build equally. Check your makefiles, that's where the difference is.

Comment: what is the reason why you don't want AVX?

Comment: grep Makefile (or other build related files) for avx (or 'native' ri whichever equivalent for you compiler is, if you are building on CPU with AVX support)?

Comment: **@MSalters**: I have one sln file and one Makefile, how do I check them for difference? I checked CL and LINK parameters for difference, and tried to use the same parameters, I did not get the same results...

**bolov**: Prorgams compiled with AVX can't be run on older PC's that have CPU without AVX support

**Dan M**.: no sign of AVX anywhere in project files

Comment: add `/arch:SSE2` to all flags except MT one and check the result

Comment: and another question is how you'd determined that `.exe` has avx instructions when you dont have a clue what `nmake` is.

Comment: Your AVX/AVX2 comes together with `/O2` or `/Ox` compiler optimization options.

Comment: *Алексей Неудачин* - I tried that, but this flag is not even supported in 64-bit version of compiler ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620901.aspx )
I found that it contains AVX instructions because when it crashes I see 'invalid instruction vmovdqu' error message, and also I see this instruction in disassembled version of exe.

*Victor Gubin* - thank you, I will try to switch to different /O flags

Comment: @Victor Gubin - my VS solution file also defines /O2 and no /arch and compiles without AVX support (and does not crash on CPU without AVX)

Comment: @MiroJanosik Are you sure those CPU really produced before 2011 i.e. less then Intel Sandy Bridge or AMD Bulldozer. In any case if you compile using something like Visual Studio 2008 - 2012 I suppose cl would not generate AVX instruction set with /02 since most of those days common AMD64 based  processors doesn't support this instruction set.

Comment: @VictorGubin - I have to compile with VS 2017 because of new c++ support; and what else could it be? CPU info program shows that AVX instructions are not supported on CPU + it shows 'invalid operation vmovdqu' in crash.

Comment: @MiroJanosik It seems like known [VS 2017 bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166375/avx-instructions-generated-since-155-update.html). You can do a trick with pragma or you can try to use MinGW 64 with [MSYS2 build](https://www.msys2.org/), Itel C++ compiler, llvm/clang fow windows etc. 2. Make sure you are running release version from IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way, find an old PC without AVX, run your app in debugger, it’ll crash with invalid instruction runtime error and will trap to debugger. This way you’ll immediately find out what code compiled into that instruction.

Another, harder way, write a C# console app that disassembles the compiled DLL or EXE, and searches for AVX instruction. You’ll need `Gee.External.Capstone` nuget package for disassembling, `PeNet` package for parsing into sections. [Also this code to disassemble](https://gist.github.com/Const-me/c69cce18dd6bf1c81f89). The `disassembleStreamEx` method will return you the stream of the instructions. Search for X86InstructionGroup.AVX or X86InstructionGroup.AVX2 instructions, print addresses, then use e.g. WinDBG + PDB file to translate addresses into source code location.

**Update:** before doing that, search your codebase for files containing `_mm256_`, and `*.asm` files. If you’re lucky you won’t have to do anything else.

Comment: I know that it contains AVX (because it crashes and I see avx instructions in disassembled code), I want to know where it comes from (some obj file, or some flag) during the compilation so I can turn it off.

For disassembling there is already tool in VS commandline: "dumpbin /disasm binary >binary.asm"

Comment: If it crashes, a debugger will show you exactly where. VS debugger will just break execution and show you exact source location of the crash. WinDBG can do it offline, collect a crash dump https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps then load dump + debug symbols + binaries into WinDBG and run `!analyze -v`

Comment: You don’t need just a disassembler, you need disassembler that you can consume programmatically, to search for specific classes of instructions. It’s hard to find AVX instructions in a disassembly of a huge module. If you don’t like capstone you can parse disassembled .asm file to search for AVX but it’s IMO harder.

Comment: Please can I get something from crash dump if binary was built without debug symbols? (release binary)
When I build binary with adding /Z7 for debug symbols and link with /DEBUG /PDB:"program.pdb" then ... it does not crash anymore.

Comment: Yes, crash dump analysis works for release builds, too. You need .pdb file[s] made by your linker, exactly same .pdb made by the build you’re running (rebuilding invalidates it).

Comment: If you don’t have .pdb for release builds, go to Configuration Properties / Linker / Debugging, set “Generate Program Database File” value to `$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb`

Comment: BTW you can debug your release builds too, if you want. Compared to WinDBG, VS debugger is _much_ easier to use.